# Tratar e Salvar lista na Controller Asp.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net

Eu tenho uma Classe Cliente, Que usa 1 ou varios sistemas.

```
    public class ClienteEmpresa : Pessoa
    {
    public virtual ICollection<TipoDeSistemas> TipoDeSistemas { get; set; }
    }
```

Na minha Action Get Create eu busco a lista no banco e envio para a view

```
   public ActionResult _frmCadastroCliente()
        {
            ViewBag.SistemaComercial = new SelectList(db.TipoDeSistemaDb, "Id", "Descricao");
            return PartialView();
        }
```

Na minha View eu tenho um select que recebe essa lista.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12" style="margin-left:10px; min-width:100%;">
        <div class="form-group" style="margin-left:-7px; margin-top:17px;margin-bottom:11px;">
            <label for="vat" class=" form-control-label">Tipo De Sistema</label>
                @Html.DropDownList("SistemaComercial", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "standardSelect", multiple = "multiple" })
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Na minha Action Post Create eu recebo uma array de Ids.

```
public ActionResult Create(ClienteEmpresaViewModel clienteEmpresaviewmodel, int[] SistemaComercial)
{
  //Aqui que eu quero saber como tratar e salvar essa lista.
  //Eu tentei Assim
   foreach (var sistema in SistemaComercial)
    {
     //Mas não sei como salvar.
    }
}
```

Alguém poderia me dar uma dica de como atribuir essa lista para o meu Cliente?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu Consegui resolver, da seguinte maneira. (se mais alguém passar pela msm coisa).

```
public ActionResult Create(ClienteEmpresaViewModel clienteEmpresaviewmodel,List<int> SistemaComercial)
    {
      ClienteEmpresa cl = new ClienteEmpresa();
       foreach (var sistema in SistemasComerciais)
       {
        TipoDeSistemas ts = db.TipoDeSistemaDb.Find(sistema);
        cl.TipoDeSistemas.Add(ts);
       }
    }
```